# How Can i Create procedure to forbid duplicated email?

Tags: sql, linq

I Have registration Form (asp.net) that include for text box . one of them is email text box . and iam  using Linq To SQL . 
i have been write procedure   to forbid duplication

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckEmail ( @email NVARCHAR(50) )
AS
    BEGIN 
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT C.Email
                            FROM Customer C
                            WHERE Email = @email )
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Customer
                        ( Email )
                    VALUES ( @email ) 
            END

        ELSE
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            END


    END
```

is this a good way? How can I return error?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. I realize English may not be your first language but please try to edit your question so that it is more understandable. Communicate what action the user is taking, what action you want your code to do, and what you have tried. You can provide sample code as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RAISEERROR()` function to return error. Also because you never tried to insert a duplicate email you do not need to `ROLLBACK`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckEmail ( @email NVARCHAR(50) )
AS
    BEGIN 
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT C.Email
                            FROM Customer C
                            WHERE Email = @email )
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Customer
                        ( Email )
                    VALUES ( @email ) 
            END

        ELSE
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(100) = 'ERROR: Attempt to insert duplicate email address'
                RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,11,1)

                RETURN
            END 
    END
```

this is assuming you using [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) if you are using a different DBMS just look up raise error function for your system.

Note: When you return SQL Error you need to make sure that application code knows how to handle it instead of just crashing.

Comment: how can i use it in linq to sql ?

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean. Use procedure from linq or how to handle errors in linq?

Comment: no , have textbox that i want to use this procedure when  email was duplicate return me error ?